# toggle visibility on combination of classes

Tags: jquery, show-hide

I am building a side panel for a map, and there is list of paths.
Each path can be marked with 3 flags **walk**, **bike**, **drive**.
All combinations of flags are possible but there should be at least one.

My task is to create 3 filter buttons that hide and show elements of the list, based on there type.

**EDIT:**
All rows are marked with (combination of) classes based on there types `.walk`, `.bike`, `.drive`.
A row should be visible if **ANY** of the filters coresponding to his classes is active.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GBQ65/)

This is a working example that does the job... but is not very pretty:

```
function updatePathTypes(){ 
    var w = $('#filter_walk.active').length;
    var b = $('#filter_bike.active').length;
    var d = $('#filter_drive.active').length;
    console.log('w:'+w +', b:'+b+', d:'+d);

    if(w){
        $('.walk:not(:visible)').show();
        if(!b && !d){ //w=true, b=false, d=false
            $('.bike:visible:not(.walk)').hide();
            $('.drive:visible:not(.walk)').hide();
        }else{
            if (!d) { //w=true, b=true, d=false
                $('.drive:visible:not(.bike):not(.walk)').hide();
            }else{   //w=true, b=?, d=true
                $('.drive:not(:visible):not(.walk)').show();
            }
            if (!b) {//w=true, b=false, d=true
                $('.bike:visible:not(.drive):not(.walk)').hide();
            }else{  //w=true, b=true, d=?
                $('.bike:not(:visible):not(.drive):not(.walk)').show();
            }
        }
    } else {
        if (!b && !d) { //w=false, b=false, d=false
            $('.walk:visible').hide();
            $('.bike:visible').hide();
            $('.drive:visible').hide();
        } else {
            if (!d) { //w=false, b=true, d=false
                $('.drive:visible:not(.bike)').hide();
            } else { //w=false, b=?, d=true
                $('.drive:not(:visible)').show();
                $('.walk:visible:not(.drive)').hide();
            }
            if (!b) { //w=false, b=false, d=true
                $('.bike:visible:not(.drive)').hide();
            } else { //w=false, b=true, d=?
                $('.bike:not(:visible)').show();
                $('.walk:visible:not(.bike):not(.drive)').hide();
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Please have in mind that it is very important to hide or show one `div` JUST ONCE  and only if NEEDED upon the function call, as later the `hide`/`show` will be changed to some animation.

Is there a more cleaner solution or some concept that I m missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code can be *massively* simplified by storing the related classnames of the buttons in an array, and joining those values to create the selector. Try this:

```
$('.path-filters span').on('click',function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    updatePathTypes();
});

function updatePathTypes() { 
    var classFilter = [];
    $('#filter_walk').hasClass('active') && classFilter.push('.walk');
    $('#filter_bike').hasClass('active') && classFilter.push('.bike');
    $('#filter_drive').hasClass('active') && classFilter.push('.drive');

    $('.walk, .bike, .drive').hide(); // hide all
    $(classFilter.join()).show(); // show selected
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/GBQ65/1/)

Comment: a row should be shown if any of his flag is active, not the exact combination (editing).
Also as mentioned hiding all first will result badly if an animation is applied

Comment: `a row should be shown if any of his flag is active` this does that. `hiding all first will result badly if an animation is applied` you can change the `hide()` / `show()` to whatever is required, `fadeOut()` or `animate()` for example. All I did was replicate the behaviour of your current code, as per the request.

Comment: Don't use a delayed hide/show. Use fadeIn/Out for that, or animate it yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/GBQ65/5/. If you're that worried about the animation of the elements I'd start a new question as this one was about making your code more concise.

Comment: thanks, i originally tested only with hide / show / toggle
and for them it is important to not be trigger together.
FadeIn/FadeOut solves this issue easily as they seem to have build check "don`t touch it if it is not needed"